# Использование библиотек в приложении на GlassFish

Tags: glassfish, java

Здравствуйте.
Использую сервер *GlassFish 3*. Приложение строю на JSF 2 и JPA 2. Я заметил, что в *GlassFish* уже встроены все эти библиотеки. **Вопрос:**

```
     Надо ли включать в мое Web приложение 
     (WEB-INF/lib) необходимые для JSF и JPA библиотеки
          или GlassFish может использовать свои собственные?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся разница только в версиях и реализациях. Но если вы используете всё стандартное, то вы запросто можете не тянуть их с собой и всё будет работать. В конечном счёте это вопрос пэкейджингда.

Comment: Спасибо. Т.е., как я понял, если я устанавливаю мои библиотеки, сервер будет их использовать. Иначе сервер будет использовать свои?

Comment: Да, именно так